# Minimum faces required in a Person Group - Azure Face Api

Tags: python, azure, face-api

I just came over Microsoft Azure Face-API cloud-based service for enabling face recognition in my python based application. But according to my previous experience in developing Face Recognition apps, my models used to require at least 3-4 persons to classify faces correctly(to some extent).

My question is that is there any such minimum required persons that are needed to be added in a personGroup so that model can be then trained to classify faces correctly.

I just wanted to know this before I make a hasty decision of opting the Azure Face API as my primary FR platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I known for Azure Cognitive Services about Face detection and recognition, there is no minimun requirement for persons in a image. However, there are three similar services below for different scenarios that I think you must to know. The choice to use one of them is up to you.

1. [Face detection with Computer Vision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-detecting-faces). I think it's the simplest solution with out of the box for using easily on Azure.
2. [Azure Face API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/overview) for [Face detection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/concepts/face-detection) and [Face recognition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/concepts/face-recognition), also without pre-trainning like the first one.
3. If these above two can not satisfy your needs, [Azure Custom Vision Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Custom-Vision-Service/home) can support you to train your own model.

They all have the Python samples in their QuickStarts topic that you can refer to. Now, I think the only question is which one is you real needed.